# how to solve Non Static method in php 7.0 Yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii

i have recently update to php 7.0.14 in freeBSD 11 and i get error about :

> PHP Deprecated Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Non-static method common\models\Menus::getMenu() should not be called statically

And

> PHP Deprecated Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>   Non-static method common\models\Menus::getRoute() should not be called statically

here is the part of code :

```
public function getMenu()
    {
        $menu = Menus::find()
            //->andWhere(['<>','parent',0])
            ->orderBy('order')
            ->all();
            $data=[];
        foreach($menu as $menus)
        {
          if (isset($menus->parent)) {
          $submenu[$menus->id]=['label' => ($menus['menu_path'])?
              Html::img(Yii::$app->glide->createSignedUrl([
                              'glide/index',
                              'path' => $menus['menu_path'],
                              'w' => 50
                          ], true),['title' =>$menus['name']]) :
                      $menus['name'],'url'=>$menus['route'], 'options' => [
                        ['class' => 'nav nav-pills nav-stacked'],
                        ['class' => 'nav nav-second-level'],
                        ['class' => 'nav nav-third-level']
                      ],
                    ];
            $data[$menus->parent]['items']=$submenu;
          }else {
            # menu
            $data[$menus->id]= ['label' => ($menus['menu_path'])?
                Html::img(Yii::$app->glide->createSignedUrl([
                                'glide/index',
                                'path' => $menus['menu_path'],
                                'w' => 50
                            ], true),['title' =>$menus['name']]) : $menus['name']

                        ,'url'=>$menus['route']
                      ];
          }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

and

```
public function getRoutes()
    {
        $controllerlist = [];
        if ($handle = opendir('../controllers')) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') - 10) == 'Controller.php') {
                    $controllerlist[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        asort($controllerlist);
        $fulllist = [];
        foreach ($controllerlist as $controller):
            $handle = fopen('../controllers/' . $controller, "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                    if (preg_match('/public function action(.*?)\(/', $line, $display)):
                        if (strlen($display[1]) > 2):

                            $r1 = str_replace('Controller','',$controller);
                            $rs = str_replace('.php','',$r1);
                            $fulllist[strtolower($rs)][] = strtolower($rs.'/'.$display[1]);
                        endif;
                    endif;
                }
            }

            fclose($handle);
        endforeach;

        $routes=[];
        foreach($fulllist as $row)
        {
            foreach($row as $r){
                $routes[] = $r;
            }
        }

        return $routes;
    }
```

Alternatively, i've declare them to be static function by changing

> public  function getRoute and public static function getMenu

to

> public static function getRoute and public static function getMenu

in the model function, However this will affect other places were the functions are called.

Comment: In this case When you use : :: you are trying to access a method statically so your function signature should be declared as: public static function getRoute ()  and public static function getMenu()

Comment: I am afraid if this affects will affect other places. if I declare it as public static. whether it will affect other places ?

Comment: You may also use something like this calling object.

 $classObj = new getRoute () ;
 $classObj->getData();

Comment: mark comment as useful if its really helped you